# How to replace single backslash(\) to double backslash(\\) in java?

Tags: java

I have this string in my Java code which is coming from a URL:

```
String str = "C:\Program Files\Text.txt";
```

And I want to replace it to make it somewhat like this

```
String str = "C:\\\Program Files\\\Text.txt";
```

But Java isn't accepting str and also I cannot manually make the single backslash as double backslash everytime because it's coming from an URL. The code is showing this error below:

> error: illegal escape character

> String str = "C:\Program Files\Text.txt";

I have already tried "replace" and "replaceAll" but the issue is, it is not accepting my input so obviously it is not compiling.
All in all my question is how do I take this string as input, `String str = "C:\Program Files\Text.txt";`

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "C:\Program Files\Text.txt";
        str = str.replace("\", "\\");
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that \ has special meaning in a String, it's called an escape character. For example, if you wanted to write use a double quote character in a string... how would you do that if the double quite character ended the string? The answer is you use this special character and you *escape* the special meaning of it, and use `\"`. So to write a literal backslash, you escape it the same way: `\\ `. To write 2 of those, you do that twice: `\\\\ `. So use this: `str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");`

Answer (score 3):

Backslash is an escape sequence character, You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html). It needs to be prefixed with `\`.You need to do this:

```java
String str = "C:\\Program Files\\Text.txt";
str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer. Thanks for noticing